# count items from json array that start with string, at root level

Tags: jq

There is a json document which contains an array of strings. e.g.

```json
[
  "abc",
  "xabc",
  "abcd",
  "xyz"
]
```

via jq i want to count the items that start with a string. f.e. `abc`

I would expect that

`jq -c '.[] | select(startswith("abc"))' | wc -l | xargs`

return `2` but it throws an error: `jq: error: startwith/1 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1`

The similar request with `contains` instead of `startswith`

`jq -c '.[] | select(contains("abc"))' | wc -l | xargs` returns `3` (what is correct, for contains)

Comment: How about `map(select(startswith("abc"))) | length`, or more efficiently `reduce (.[] | select(startswith("abc"))) as $_ (0; . + 1)`? (`startswith` has an `s` in the middle)

Comment: The filter is spelled [`startswith`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#startswith)

Comment: startswith (with S in the middle) is the missing link. Thanks!